# Put heading TEXT as input value jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to know how to copy the text from one heading:
ex:

```
<h2 class="customTitleHead">This is a Heading</h2>
```

into an input value:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="rProvider" class="rr_small_input" />
```

In the end i need to have the input text value of the heading

```
<input type="text" value="This is a Heading" name="rProvider" class="rr_small_input" />
```

I tried using but i receive nothing into my input.

```
jQuery(function () {
  jQuery(".rr_small_input[name='rProvider']").val(jQuery("h2.customTitleHead").val());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val()` returns (or sets) `value` attribute of an `input`, `select`, `textarea`, `progress` elements. `H2` element doesn't have value attribute obviously. `text()` is the method to return inner text of an element.

```
jQuery(".rr_small_input[name='rProvider']").val(jQuery("h2.customTitleHead").text());
```

Comment: @Андрей Почекуев : It worked. Will be nice an explanation:) Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` only works on `input`, `select`, `textarea` and `progress` elements (as far as I'm aware; as only these have a `value` property. For every other element you'd use [jQuery's `.text()` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
jQuery("h2.customTitleHead").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2 id='myHeader' class="customTitleHead">This is a Heading</h2>
<input id='myInput' type="text" value="This is a Heading" name="rProvider" class="rr_small_input" />


<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myInput').val($('#myHeader').val());
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I would have done this:

```
$('input').val($('.customTitleHead').html())
```

So you grab the `html` from the class `.customTitleHead` and then put in as the `input` val. Simple.

**Note:** You can also use `.text()` instead of `.html()` I'm just used to using `.html()`

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/3LdHg/)

---

If you want a certain `input` use the class instead of the `input`. So:

```
$('.rr_small_input').val($('.customTitleHead').html())
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/3LdHg/2/)